# Find maximal integral curve for $x \frac{d}{dx}$ on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: manifolds, vector-fields

I need t find the maximal integral curve starting at point $p \in \mathbb{R}$ of a vector field $x \frac{d}{dx}$ on $\mathbb{R}$.

Now, I know that for finding the integral field, I need to solve $$\frac{dx}{dt} = x $$

Solving them will give these two equations :- $$\ln x = t + c_1  \space $$ So the integral curve would be $x(t) = \exp(t+ c_1)$

I don't get what to do with this to find the maximal integral curve. In general how do we find the maximal integral curves?

Comment: What is $y(t)$ doing here? The vector field you're looking at is a vector field on $\mathbb R$, so its integral curve is going to be a map taking values in $\mathbb R$, not in $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: You're almost there. Try writing down the explicit definitions of what it means for $x(t)$ to be an integral curve of $x\frac{d}{dx}$, what it means to start at $p\in\mathbb R$, and what it means to be maximal. And then compare those definitions to the formula you found.